# How to format pandas dataframe when writing to csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I have a Pandas dataframe with the following data

```
0 5
1 7
2 3
```

The first column is the index.

What is the easiest way to get this written to a csv file (space delimited) so the output will look like this?

```
|index 0 |features 5
|index 1 |features 7
|index 2 |features 3
```

By csv file, I mean writing a file like this:

```
test.to_csv('test_map2.txt', sep=' ', header=None, index=False)
```

Comment: That is not a csv. Please show at actual csv as you would like it, using commas to separate values.

Comment: I have added some information to my question. By csv file, I mean the output of the Pandas to_csv function. Not necessarily that the separator is a comma. In my case I want to use space as the separator.

Comment: first convert your dataframe to the desired format, you can use apply function on the index and column then save it with `sep=' '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can proceed as follows

```
test.index = test.index.map(lambda x:"|index " + str(x))
test.ix[:,0] = test.ix[:,0].apply(lambda x:'|features ' + str(x))
test.to_csv('test_map2.txt', sep=' ', header=None, index=False)
```

Comment: This approach looks like exactly what I want. The first statement worked fine, but on the second one failed with an error (TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'). I had to change "test[:,0]" into "test[test.columns[0]]".

Comment: that is a good approach, you can also use the ix, indexing, i modified it now

Comment: Great! Notice that str(x) would also be required at the end of line #2

Answer (score 0):

To have the index as an implicit column in the csv:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(data=[5, 7, 3]))
with io.open('df.csv', 'wb') as file: df.to_csv(file, header=False)
```

gives

```
0,5
1,7
2,3
```

or if you have more interesting index values then use

```
import pandas as pd
import io
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(data=[5, 7, 3]))
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
with io.open('df.csv', 'wb') as file: df.to_csv(file)
```

which gives

```
,index,data
0,0,5
1,1,7
2,2,3
```

**to get spaces** the use

```
import pandas as pd
import io
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(data=[5, 7, 3]))
df.index.rename
with io.open('df.csv', 'wb') as file: df.to_csv(file, sep=" ", header=False)
```

which gives

```
0 5
1 7
2 3
```

although spaces are probably best to avoid.

The closer resemblance to your `|header` is perhaps

```
import pandas as pd
import io
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(data=[5, 7, 3]))
df.index.rename
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: '|' +  col + ' ' + str(x))
with io.open('df.csv', 'wb') as file: df.to_csv(file, sep=" ", header=False, index=False, quotechar=' ')
```

giving

```
 |index  0   |data  5 
 |index  1   |data  7 
 |index  2   |data  3
```

Comment: But, how do I get the text "|index " prefixed to the values in the index column and the text "|features " prefixed to the second column in the output file (and in the dataframe if that is required)?